# Save currentTime as long (AndroidStudio/libgdx

Tags: java, android, time, timer, libgdx

I am currently coding a game with Android Studio in the style of FlappyBird. I have two Cooldowns that give the user the possibility to use extra abilities.

In the main game view you can see 2 images that are grey and a timer under them. The timer goes from 10 to 0 and when zero is reached the number disappears, the image gets colored and the user knows he is able to activate the ability in the pause screen.

The problem:

When the game is starting the timer starts also and goes down as i wanted. But if the user enters the Pause Menu the Timer should stop and if he leaves it the Timer should run again.

I have a

```
long startTime = 0;
```

and a

```
long elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
```

It all works but I cannot save the current time in a long and can't find any function for it!

I know the code is very long but the important part is in the drawWorld()-method in the if statement GameState.Running.

```
public class PlaneGame extends ApplicationAdapter{
private static final float PLANE_JUMP_IMPULSE = 350;
private static final float GRAVITY = -20;
private static final float PLANE_VELOCITY_X = 200;
private static final float PLANE_START_Y = 240;
private static final float PLANE_START_X = 50;
private static final int STATE_START = 0;
private static final int STATE_RUNNING = 1;
private static final int STATE_OVER = 2;

SpriteBatch batch;
OrthographicCamera camera;
OrthographicCamera uiCamera;
Texture background;
TextureRegion ground;
float groundOffsetX = 0;
TextureRegion ceiling;
TextureRegion rock;
TextureRegion rockDown;
TextureRegion planeSmall;
TextureRegion planeSmallBlack;
Animation plane;
TextureRegion ready;
TextureRegion gameOver;
TextureRegion pause;
BitmapFont font;

Vector2 planePosition = new Vector2();
Vector2 planeVelocity = new Vector2();
float planeStateTime = 0;
Vector2 gravity = new Vector2();
Array<Rock> rocks = new Array<Rock>();

GameState gameState = GameState.Start;          /*neeeeeeewwwww*/
int score = 0;
long startTime = 0;
long startTime2;
long elapsedTime;
long savedTime;
boolean wantToSeeTime = true;
boolean wantToSeeTimePause = true;
float timeCdRock = 0;
float timeCdPlane = 0;
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle();

Music music;
Sound point;
Sound explode;

//this gets called repeatedly to run the game
@Override
public void render () {
    //clear the screen so we can draw the next one
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    long saveTime = elapsedTime;
    //update the position of the plane and rocks
    updateWorld();
    elapsedTime = saveTime;
    //now draw the updated screen
    drawWorld();
}

//initialize objects and load assets when game starts
@Override

public void create () {
    startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();                                                       /*Neeeewwwwwwwww !!!*/
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener()));
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    uiCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    uiCamera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    uiCamera.update();

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("arial.fnt"));

    background = new Texture("background.png"); 
    ground = new TextureRegion(new Texture("ground.png"));
    ceiling = new TextureRegion(ground);
    ceiling.flip(true, true);

    rock = new TextureRegion(new Texture("rock.png"));
    rockDown = new TextureRegion(rock);
    rockDown.flip(false, true);

    Texture frame1 = new Texture("plane1.png");
    frame1.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    Texture frame2 = new Texture("plane2.png");
    Texture frame3 = new Texture("plane3.png");

    planeSmall = new TextureRegion(new Texture("planeSmall.png"));
    planeSmallBlack = new TextureRegion(new Texture("planeSmallBlack.png"));

    ready = new TextureRegion(new Texture("ready.png"));
    gameOver = new TextureRegion(new Texture("gameover.png"));
    pause = new TextureRegion(new Texture("pause.png"));

    plane = new Animation(0.05f, new TextureRegion(frame1), new TextureRegion(frame2), new TextureRegion(frame3), new TextureRegion(frame2));
    plane.setPlayMode(PlayMode.LOOP);

    music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music.mp3"));
    music.setLooping(true);
    music.play();

    point = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("point.ogg"));
    explode = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("explode.wav"));

    resetWorld();
}

//reset the state of the game
private void resetWorld() {
    score = 0;
    startTime = 0;
    groundOffsetX = 0;
    planePosition.set(PLANE_START_X, PLANE_START_Y);
    planeVelocity.set(0, 0);
    gravity.set(0, GRAVITY);
    camera.position.x = 400;

    //randomize the position and direction of the rocks
    rocks.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        boolean isDown = MathUtils.randomBoolean();
        rocks.add(new Rock(700 + i * 200, isDown?480-rock.getRegionHeight(): 0, isDown? rockDown: rock));
    }
}

//use the time elapsed since the last call to render() to determine how much to update the game
private void updateWorld() {

    float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    planeStateTime += deltaTime;

    /*if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        if(gameState == STATE_START) {
            gameState = STATE_RUNNING;
        }
        if(gameState == STATE_RUNNING) {
            planeVelocity.set(PLANE_VELOCITY_X, PLANE_JUMP_IMPULSE);
        }
        if(gameState == STATE_OVER) {
            gameState = STATE_START;
            resetWorld();
        }
    }*/

    if(gameState != GameState.Start) planeVelocity.add(gravity);

    planePosition.mulAdd(planeVelocity, deltaTime);

    camera.position.x = planePosition.x + 350;      
    if(camera.position.x - groundOffsetX > ground.getRegionWidth() + 400) {
        groundOffsetX += ground.getRegionWidth();
    }

    rect1.set(planePosition.x + 20, planePosition.y, plane.getKeyFrames()[0].getRegionWidth() - 20, plane.getKeyFrames()[0].getRegionHeight());
    for(Rock r: rocks) {
        //if the rock is off the screen, give it a new location in front of the plane
        if(camera.position.x - r.position.x > 400 + r.image.getRegionWidth()) {
            boolean isDown = MathUtils.randomBoolean();
            r.position.x += 5 * 200;
            r.position.y = isDown?480-rock.getRegionHeight(): 0;
            r.image = isDown? rockDown: rock;
            r.counted = false;
        }
        rect2.set(r.position.x + (r.image.getRegionWidth() - 30) / 2 + 20, r.position.y, 20, r.image.getRegionHeight() - 10);

        //check if the plane crashed
        if(rect1.overlaps(rect2)) {
            if(gameState != GameState.GameOver) explode.play();
            gameState = GameState.GameOver;
            planeVelocity.x = 0;                
        }

        //award a point for not crashing into a rock
        if(r.position.x < planePosition.x && !r.counted) {
            score++;
            r.counted = true;
            point.play();
        }
    }

    //check if the plane crashed
    if(planePosition.y < ground.getRegionHeight() - 20 || 
        planePosition.y + plane.getKeyFrames()[0].getRegionHeight() > 480 - ground.getRegionHeight() + 20) {
        if(gameState != GameState.GameOver) explode.play();
        gameState = GameState.GameOver;
        planeVelocity.x = 0;
    }       
}

//draw the background, rocks, and plane to the screen and possibly some ui text
private void drawWorld() {
    elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background, camera.position.x - background.getWidth() / 2, 0);
    for(Rock rock: rocks) {
        batch.draw(rock.image, rock.position.x, rock.position.y);
    }
    batch.draw(ground, groundOffsetX, 0);
    batch.draw(ground, groundOffsetX + ground.getRegionWidth(), 0);
    batch.draw(ceiling, groundOffsetX, 480 - ceiling.getRegionHeight());
    batch.draw(ceiling, groundOffsetX + ceiling.getRegionWidth(), 480 - ceiling.getRegionHeight());
    batch.draw(plane.getKeyFrame(planeStateTime), planePosition.x, planePosition.y);
    batch.end();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    if(gameState == GameState.Start) {
        batch.draw(ready, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - ready.getRegionWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - ready.getRegionHeight() / 2);
    }
    if(gameState == GameState.GameOver) {
        batch.draw(gameOver, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - gameOver.getRegionWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - gameOver.getRegionHeight() / 2);
    }
    if(gameState == GameState.GameOver || gameState == GameState.Running) {
        font.draw(batch, "" + score, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 60);
    }
    if(gameState == GameState.Running || gameState == GameState.Pause) {
        //font.draw(batch, "" + (10 - elapsedTime), (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) / 3, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 260);
        if(wantToSeeTime){
            font.draw(batch, "" + (5 - elapsedTime), (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) / 3, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 260);
        }
        if((5 -(elapsedTime) > 0)) {
            batch.draw(planeSmallBlack, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) / 3, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 250);
        }else  {
            batch.draw(planeSmall, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) / 3, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 250);
            wantToSeeTime = false;
        }
    }
    if(gameState == GameState.Pause){
        batch.draw(pause, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - pause.getRegionWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - pause.getRegionHeight() / 2);
        if(wantToSeeTimePause){
            font.draw(batch, "" + (savedTime), (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) / 3, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 260);
        }
    }
    batch.end();
}


//object to hold all pertinent information for a rock
static class Rock {
    Vector2 position = new Vector2();
    TextureRegion image;
    boolean counted;

    public Rock(float x, float y, TextureRegion image) {
        this.position.x = x;
        this.position.y = y;
        this.image = image;
    }
}

                            // Neeeeeeeewwwww
static enum GameState {
    Start, Running, GameOver, Pause
}

private class MyGestureListener implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        if(gameState == GameState.Start) {
            gameState = GameState.Running;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if(gameState == GameState.Running) {
            planeVelocity.set(PLANE_VELOCITY_X, PLANE_JUMP_IMPULSE);
        }
        if(gameState == GameState.GameOver) {
            gameState = GameState.Start;
            resetWorld();
        }
        /*if((gameState == GameState.Pause) && (count == 2)) {
            planeVelocity.set(PLANE_VELOCITY_X, PLANE_JUMP_IMPULSE);
            gravity.set(0,GRAVITY);
            gameState = GameState.Running;

        }*/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        if(gameState == GameState.Running) {
            planePosition.set(planePosition.x, planePosition.y);
            planeVelocity.set(0,0);
            gravity.set(0, 0);
            savedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            wantToSeeTime = false;
            wantToSeeTimePause = true;
            gameState = GameState.Pause;



        } else {
            planeVelocity.set(PLANE_VELOCITY_X, PLANE_JUMP_IMPULSE);
            gravity.set(0,GRAVITY);
            wantToSeeTime = true;
            wantToSeeTimePause = false;
            elapsedTime -= savedTime;
            gameState = GameState.Running;


        }

        /*if(gameState == GameState.Pause) {
            planeVelocity.set(PLANE_VELOCITY_X, PLANE_JUMP_IMPULSE);
            gravity.set(0,GRAVITY);
            gameState = GameState.Running;
        }*/

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        return false;
    }


    public void pinchStop() {

    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ideally, for a game, you wouldn't use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  You should have a game loop method which calculates how long between each iteration of this loop.  You would then add this value to `elapsedTime`.  This will handle your problem and also differences in gamespeed caused by different hardware.

Comment: But to answer your question `long time = System.currentTimeMillis();` should do it.

Comment: Hi you can use epoch time to save

Answer (score 0):

You can use joda time for advanced operations
Please check the link for your reference
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your game runs as part of a loop. Ideally what you should have is a starting time when the ability is activated, which counts down during the cooldown based on how much time has elapsed since the last iteration of your loop. For example, for an ability with a 10 second cooldown:

```
final long abilityLength = 10 * 1000;
long cooldownRemaining = 0;
long lastTimestamp;
boolean isPaused = false;

private void doAbility() {
    if (cooldownRemaining <= 0) {
        cooldownRemaining = abilityLength;
    }
}

public void main(int[] args) {
    lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(true) { // your main game loop

        // Time (in ms) elapsed since the last iteration of this loop
        long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimestamp;

        ... // Other game code

        if (cooldownRemaining > 0 && !isPaused) {
            // Subtract the delta from the remaing cooldown time.
            cooldownRemaining -= delta;
        }

        lastTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```